# How are a matrix, a result matrix of a couple of matrix multiplies, the inverse of that matrix, and doing the matrix multiplies backwards connected?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

The matrices I use are for the canvas in webbrowsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/transform
where `[a,b,c,d,e,f]` is actually described as
$$ \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     a&c&e \\
     b&d&f \\
     0&0&1
  \end{array} \right]
$$

Given I have a starting matrix `s =`
$$ \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     1&0&0 \\
     0&1&0
  \end{array} \right]
$$
and I have lot of matrices to multiply `s` with: `m1 ... mn` with 6 random numbers themselves, like
$$\eqalign{
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
m1r1 & m1r3 & m1r5 \\
m1r2 & m1r4 & m1r6 \\
\end{array}
\right]
 to
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
mnr1 & mnr3 & mnr5 \\
mnr2 & mnr4 & mnr6 \\
\end{array}
\right]
}$$

When I multiply `s` starting with `m1` to `mn` I get `sforward`.

When I multiply `s` starting with `mn` to `m1` I get `sbackward`.

When I invert `sforward` I get `sfi`.

When I invert `sbackward`I get `sbi`.

Is there ONE matrix to multiply `sforward` with to get `sbackward`?

Is there ONE matrix to multiply `sfi` with to get `sbi`?

Is there ONE matrix to multiply `sforward` with to get `sbi`?

Just some real life example matrices for `m1...mn` for multiplying:
`["matrix:1,0,0,0.7741935483870968,0,116.74193548387098","matrix:1,0,0,0.9166666666666666,0,43.08333333333337","matrix:1,0,0,0.8709408825978352,0,61.594504579517036","matrix:1,0,0,0.7332695984703633,0,127.29923518164435"]`

I seriously hope to get rid of this amount of matrices somehow.

For multiplying and inverting I use these javascript functions:

```
function matrixMultiply(multiM=[1,0,0,1,0,0],onM=[1,0,0,1,0,0]) {
    onM = [].concat(onM);
    var m11 = onM[0]*multiM[0] + onM[2]*multiM[1];
    var m12 = onM[1]*multiM[0] + onM[3]*multiM[1];
    var m21 = onM[0]*multiM[2] + onM[2]*multiM[3];
    var m22 = onM[1]*multiM[2] + onM[3]*multiM[3];
    var dx = onM[0]*multiM[4] + onM[2]*multiM[5] + onM[4];
    var dy = onM[1]*multiM[4] + onM[3]*multiM[5] + onM[5];

    onM[0] = m11; onM[1] = m12; onM[2] = m21;
    onM[3] = m22; onM[4] = dx; onM[5] = dy;
    return onM;
};

function matrixInvert(onM=[1,0,0,1,0,0]) {
    onM = [].concat(onM); 
    var d = 1 / (onM[0]*onM[3] - onM[1]*onM[2]);
    var m0 = onM[3]*d; var m1 = -onM[1]*d; var m2 = -onM[2]*d;
    var m3 = onM[0]*d; var m4 = d*(onM[2]*onM[5] - onM[3]*onM[4]); var m5 = d*(onM[1]*onM[4] - onM[0]*onM[5]);
    onM[0] = m0; onM[1] = m1; onM[2] = m2;
    onM[3] = m3; onM[4] = m4; onM[5] = m5;
    return onM;
};
```

Comment: To start, it is unclear what sort of "multiplying" of matrices you are intending here but it is not what most of us would have considered multiplying of matrices.  The shapes don't work out correctly.  Second, your notation is convoluted and you refer to things such as "inverting" these objects... whatever they should formally be described as... which again does not correspond to what we would normally call inverting for what we would normally call matrices.

Comment: Next... while sometimes helpful to provide realworld examples... there is *no* reason to have your examples be such that they have that many decimal places.  Those aren't going to help get across concepts any better than if they were whole numbers or numbers that go to only one or two decimal places rather than 15 decimal places.  All that accomplished was to make it more difficult to read.

Comment: I can put the sample in a better form, but I'm not sure: Isn't there something like impossible matrices for multiplying or inverting?

Comment: That makes more sense now that it is clear the matrices are actually $\begin{bmatrix}a&c&e\\b&d&f\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and not $\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\end{bmatrix}$ or $\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c&d&e&f\end{bmatrix}$ or something else...  I still haven't fully checked that your multiplication or inversion functions are correctly defined, but the notation you used certainly didn't help anything

Comment: I'm ready to change or add any information needed! I'm so sorry I got some matrices wrong first. I have pulled this code's part along all the time, and didn't look back, that's why I got it so wrong. But now I really have to tidy this up. (It's so embarrasing, as an even longer time ago I was very very good in maths.)

Comment: In the end, it sounds as though you are asking if rather than $A(B(CD))$ you can write this a different way, the answer is yes.  You could write $(ABC)D$.  If you are asking, given only the final result of $ABC$, can we figure out what is $CBA$, the answer is no... there is not enough information.  If you are asking, "*can we multiply $ABC$ by something to get $CBA$*"... well, for the *specific* example of $ABC$, yes we could multiply it on the right by $(ABC)^{-1}CBA$... but that is hardly useful and what we multiplied by very much depended on what $A,B,C$ were.

Comment: "*Isn't there something like impossible matrices for...inverting*"  Yes.  In your context, that occurs when `onM[0]*onM[3]-onM[1]*onM[2] == 0`, giving a division by zero error.

Comment: I always suspected these functions, that I found on the internet, to not be fail save.

Comment: Oh, they're correct... but only once the context was made clear.  It would have been far clearer in my opinion if the matrices were fully written out and were written out in a far more standardized way, such as `[[a,c,e],[b,d,f],[0,0,1]]`, even if the `[0,0,1]` was unnecessary.  The savings in terms of memory and speed are not worth the loss of readability in my opinion.